# Installation of package ‘bigmemory’ had non-zero

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I have installed bigmemory version 4.4.14. Now I am trying to upgrade it to bigmemory version 4.6.1 and got following error msg:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: bigmemory.so]
> Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘bigmemory’
>
> - removing ‘/home/super/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/bigmemory’
> - restoring previous ‘/home/super/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/bigmemory’ Warning in
>   install.packages :   installation of package ‘bigmemory’ had non-zero
>   exit status

I have tried to upgrade via:

```
 Rstudio (Tools -> check for package update).

 install.packages("bigmemory")

 devtools::install_github("kaneplusplus/bigmemory")
```

Updated and upgraded ubntu and R packages:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

sudo apt install r-cran-bigmemory

update.packages(ask = FALSE)

install.packages("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/bigmemory_4.6.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0 LAPACK:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
> LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8     [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
> LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
> LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
> LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.2.0
> tools_4.2.0

I am struggling from few days but still getting the same problem, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part of the error message is “cannot find -luuid”. Which means that you are missing the **libuuid** system dependency, which you will need to install separately before you can install the R package. Since you’re on Ubuntu, you can do this via

```sh
sudo apt install uuid-dev
```

In general, when faced with this kind of error messages, it usually helps to search the relevant part of the error message online, which will lead to instructions on how to install the missing system dependencies (their package name isn’t always obvious, as above).